# jQuery if hasclass addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

this is what i have so far - i'm trying to get the text only to show when the 'timelineTile' is made bigger..

```
$(function () {
    $('.timelineTile').click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $('.selected').children().not(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

        if($('.selected').children().hasClass("clicked")){
            $('.details').addClass('show');
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
        $('.timelineTile').removeClass('clicked');
        $('.details').removeClass('show');
    });
});
```

[fiddle also](http://jsfiddle.net/gjyksjuh/)

Comment: not getting what is the exact problem, will you please elaborate more?

Comment: Do you mean "trying to get the text to only show"? At the moment the position of *only* binds it to *text* not *show*.

Comment: i want the text only to show when the box is clicked expands red.. and when when you click on another the text then hides like the box gets goes back to how it was and then click on other box and shows the text, so like the boxes do but with the text too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following css as well to show text only when box is bigger

```
.timelineTile table{
    display: none;
}
.timelineTile.clicked table{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/devools/gjyksjuh/1/
try that fiddle?

```
$(function () {
    $('.timelineTile').click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
         $('.selected').children().not(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

        if($('.selected').children().hasClass("clicked")){
            $('.details').removeClass('show');
           $(this).children('.details').addClass('show');
}
    });


    $(document).click(function () {
        $('.timelineTile').removeClass('clicked');
       $('.details').removeClass('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: this almost works but when clicking off the same box it stays